# Using "Group By" with "Join" on Mysql

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables "Texts" and "Authors". I want to get lastest text (Order by pubDate) each author. When I try to use a "Group By" it return an error.

Here is my tables :

Authors :

```
+----+-------+--+
| id | name  |  |
+----+-------+--+
|  1 | cat   |  |
|  2 | bird  |  |
|  3 | dog   |  |
|  4 | horse |  |
+----+-------+--+
```

Texts :

```
+----+----------+------------------+------------+
| id | authorID |      title       |  pubDate   |
+----+----------+------------------+------------+
|  1 |        1 | Life About Cat   | 2017-10-13 |
|  2 |        1 | How to be a cat? | 2017-10-12 |
|  3 |        2 | Is flying?       | 2017-10-13 |
|  4 |        2 | We love cats.    | 2017-10-11 |
+----+----------+------------------+------------+
```

Here is my working sql query **without "Group By"**:

```
SELECT texts.id AS textID, texts.title, texts.authorID  
FROM texts JOIN  authors ON authors.id = texts.authorID  
WHERE authors.pin != '1' AND authors.status='1'  
ORDER BY texts.pubDate DESC LIMIT 8
```

And here inoperative query **with "Group By"** :

```
SELECT texts.id AS textID, texts.title, texts.authorID  
FROM texts GROUP BY texts.authorID JOIN  authors ON authors.id = texts.authorID  
WHERE authors.pin != '1' AND authors.status='1'  
ORDER BY texts.pubDate DESC LIMIT 8
```

How I can get latest text from each author?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the [`SELECT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)? It explains where to put the `GROUP BY` clause (but it doesn't teach you that `GROUP BY` is completely useless for your current goal).

Comment: Why you want to use Group By clause when there is no aggregate function.  Use first query and show us the expected and actual result if there is any error. Also post some sample data.

Comment: `GROUP BY` **does not** return rows from the tables. It generates the records it returns. Accordingly it cannot be used to *get the latest text from each author*. Search for similar questions tagged [tag:greatest-n-per-group]

Comment: @AnkitBajpai sorry i've added sample data

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT A.name
      ,T.title
      ,MAX(pubDate)
FROM AUTHORS A 
INNER JOIN TEXTS T ON A.ID = T.authorID
GROUP BY A.name
        ,T.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
select * from Authors as a 
Inner join (
select MAX(pubDate) , author_id, title from `Text` group by author_id
) as t
ON t.author_id = a.id
```